# Subtracting a value from different elements of a list

Tags: python, list, integer

At first, sorry if this is a really stupid question, but im a bloody python beginner and haven't found solution yet

I have given a list and have to subtract a certain value from each element of this list

my current approach is the following:

```
positions = [10, 45, 66, 110]
subtraction_value = 8

for x in range(len(positions)):                                   
    delta_distance = int(positions[x])-subtraction_value
```

I understand that I cant subtract a value from a list
but i cant think of a way to update the position for every iteration

Hopefully the problem is somewhat understandable, english is unfortunately not my main language.

Comment: Can you give a more complete code with the declared variables?

Comment: @genericguuse, do you want to subtract a value from every element of the list without iterating the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a single line to the loop body that updates the actual list with the new value:

```
positions = [10, 45, 66, 110]
subtraction_value = 8

for x in range(len(positions)):                                   
    delta_distance = int(positions[x])-subtraction_value
    positions[x] = delta_distance
```

You can get the same result with the following comprehension:

```
positions = [x - subtraction_value for x in positions]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, now it works
but presumed i the elements in positions via

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are correct, there is also the option of using a `map`. This is especially good for when your calculations are "expensive" in terms of processing, and you want to delay them only until they are needed.

```
positions = map(lambda x: x - subtraction_value , positions)
```

Note that this doesn't create a list, `map` returns something like a generator that can be iterated on (and the calculations only happens then). To get back a list:

```
positions = list(map(lambda x: x - subtraction_value , positions))
```

Another option no one mentioned is using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
positions = [10, 45, 66, 110]
positions = np.array(positions) - subtraction_value
```